# How to Extract all the values form the regular expression extractor and pass the one by one value to Path of the http request

Tags: regex, jmeter

Here is the sample view

```
<a class="main mainAnchor current currentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form1">
            <span>Home</span>
<a class="main mainAnchor parent parentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form2">
<span>About Us</span>
<a class="sub subAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form3">
                <span>Landing</span>

<a class="sub subAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form4">
                <span>Contact Us</span>

<a class="sub subAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form5">
                <span>Hours &amp; Map</span
```

```html
In Jmeter i am using the regular expression as
(<a)\s+(class="(.+?)")\s+(tabindex="-1")\s+(href="(.+?)")>(\n|\r)\s+(<span>)(.+)
```

Using above regular Expression i am getting totol of 58 matchs
    here is the sample result for regular expresion
     Match count: 58

```
Match[1][0]=<a class="main mainAnchor current currentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form1">
                <span>some text</span>
    Match[1][1]=<a
    Match[1][2]=class="some text"
    Match[1][3]=some text
    Match[1][4]=tabindex="-1"
    Match[1][5]=href="Form1"
    Match[1][6]=Form1
    Match[1][7]=

    Match[1][8]=<span>
    Match[1][9]=some text</span>
    Match[2][0]=<a class="main mainAnchor parent parentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form2">
                <span>some text</span>
    Match[2][1]=<a
    Match[2][2]=class="some text"
    Match[2][3]=some text
    Match[2][4]=tabindex="-1"
    Match[2][5]=href="Form2"
    Match[2][6]=Form2
    Match[2][7]=

    Match[2][8]=<span>
    Match[2][9]=About Us</span>
    Match[3][0]=<a class="sub subAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form3">
                    <span>some text</span>
    Match[3][1]=<a
    Match[3][2]=class="sub subAnchor"
    Match[3][3]=sub subAnchor
    Match[3][4]=tabindex="-1"
    Match[3][5]=href="Form3"
    Match[3][6]=Form3
    Match[3][7]=

    Match[3][8]=<span>
    Match[3][9]=some text</span>
```

and i am able to get the first value like this  referenceName_g6
i want to retrive all the values of attribute href Form2,Form3,Form4 ...etc 
After getting the values i want to pass this(referenceName_g6) one by one value to Path value of next http request 
Please help on this...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You will probably get a bunch of answers saying that regex is not the tool for the job

Comment: @Vitim,if regex is not right solution then please explain what is the better solution to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be easier use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [CSS JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) instead of regular expressions. In general [parsing HMTL with regular expressions isn't a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748). Example XPath Extractor configuration would look like:

   - If response is not XHTML-compliant check `Use Tidy` box
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `Form` - it will be result variable name/prefix
   - XPath Expresssion: `//a[contains(@class, "Anchor")]/@href` - it extracts "href" attribute of all links having "Anchor" test in "class"

   [image: Xpath Extractor]
2. In order to dynamically construct the next request path add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the next request and add the following code into it's "Script" area

   ```
   Iterator it = vars.getIterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry var = (Map.Entry) it.next();
       log.info("Processing variable: " + var.getKey());
       if (var.getKey().toString().startsWith("Form")) {
           sampler.addArgument(var.getKey(), var.getValue().toString());
       }
   }
   ```

   Above code will add all the variables names which names start with "Form" as request parameters names and variables values will be parameters values. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for extra information on using Beanshell in your JMeter test.

Comment: Thank a lot Dmitri.How to pass the Xpath Reference name to Bean shell  processor script. out put of Xpath Extractor i like this 
siteMapName_1=HomePage
siteMapName_10=Reviews
siteMapName_19=ContactUs
siteMapName_2=LandingPage

Comment: Replace `startsWith("Form")` with `startsWith("siteMapName")`